# Finding hand joint points using Intel Real Sense using python

Tags: python, image-processing, realsense

How can I get the 22 joint points of each hand using Intel Real Sense D435 using python?
I could do it using normal camera, but I needed more accurate results for my project.

Comment: which model/library are you using for these 22 points ?

Comment: I am using 'realsense' library.

Comment: AFAIK that is the interface for the RGB and depth data + camera controls. You will need to find some middleware library that takes depth/RGB data and does the hand tracking for you. librealsense doesn't do that I think

Comment: Can anyone help me with finding the exact library for hand points tracking using python?